# How to search an external API with rails and display the results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search

How can I create a form/page in Rails that will let me input search parameters, which are then passed to an external API to perform the search, and then display those results in some custom pretty format?

Note, I am not asking how to consume the external service, just how to plumb a form page and a pretty results page to this search request.

This won't be an external facing page, it's just a tool I want to use to make data collection easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your destination adheres to RESTful practices, ActiveResource is probably the best tool for the job. You can find some documentation on it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html